# Renamig files which have date and extension number can be variable

Tags: batch-file

Ok let me explaned it again 
I have two location :

F:\Reporting\02.2013 in the folder "02.2013" I have below files

- `Balance Sheet_20130228_045485.xls` 3/22/2013 2:40 PM
- `Balance Sheet_20130228_024867.xls` 3/23/2013 1:40 PM
- `Balance Sheet_20130228_023556.xls` 3/23/2013 3:50 PM

F:\Statements\02.2013 in the folder "02.2013" I have below files

- `FS_20130228_045485.xls` 3/22/2013 4:40 PM
- `FS_20130228_024867.xls` 3/23/2013 1:40 PM
- `FS_20130228_023556.xls` 3/23/2013 6:45 PM

First I wants to moov the latest modified files from both the folder to Target folder :

- Target folder is `F:\accounting\02.2013`

Then I wants to rename those files as

- `Balance Sheet_20130228_023556.doc` as `BalanceMTD.xls`
- `FS_20130228_045485.doc` as `FS.xls`

note: I have to do this activity every month,

- so folder location will be change like `F:\Reporting\03.2013`
- and file name also will be change like `FS_20130331_045465.doc` 4/27/2013 4:30 PM

Can you please suggest me any batch file which can help me to do this. 
I'll change the date every month if required before execute it.

Comment: ***What?!?!?!*** Seriously : you need to **explain** what you want / what you're looking for!

Comment: Or, more politely: welcome to SO! Please explain what you are trying to do, show what code you have tried, and describe why it didn't work. Read over the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) to learn how to ask a good question.

Comment: There is no clear pattern in your renaming. Please try to explain again.

Comment: Balance Sheet_20130306_120249.xls should be renamed as BalanceMTD.xls

Comment: Why the second word is eliminated in "Balance Sheet", but not in "IC Activities"? What is the renaming rule in these cases?

Comment: Balance Sheet_xyzdate_xyznumbers.xls should be renamed as BalanceMTD.xls

Comment: So please type: `ren "Balance Sheet_xyzdate_xyznumbers.xls" BalanceMTD.xls`

Comment: Ok. But why "IC Activities_xyzdate_xyznumbers.xls" is _NOT_ renamed as ICMTD.xls??? Both names have the same format!!!! There are different rules for _the same format_??? WHAT ARE THE RENAMING RULES???

Comment: can u please give me the full coding including the folder path,F:\MY DOCUMENTS\zyx

Comment: Hi Aacini, b'coz some files are has the data MTD, some are DTD & YTD.

Comment: So we must read your mind in order to know which case is each one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will move and rename the newest file from each of your source directories:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set DateFolder=02.2013
set TargetFolder=F:\Accounting\%DateFolder%

:: Move the newest file from Reporting and rename it to BalanceMTD.xls
call :MoveAndRename "F:\Accounting\%DateFolder%" "%TargetFolder%\BalanceMTD.xls"

:: Move the newest file from Statements and rename it to FS.xls
call :MoveAndRename "F:\Statements\%DateFolder%" "%TargetFolder%\FS.xls"

:: Done
goto :eof


:MoveAndRename
set SourceFolder=%~1
set TargetFile=%~2

:: Find the newest file in the source folder
for /f "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir /b /od /a-d "%SourceFolder%"') do set "NewestFile=%%F"

:: Move and rename it to the target
move "%SourceFolder%\%NewestFile%" "%TargetFile%"

:: Done with this subroutine
goto :eof
```

I've put the bulk of the working code in a "subroutine" named `MoveAndRename`, which simply finds the newest file in a particular folder (using a `for /f` loop over a `dir /a-d` to loop over all files in order of date, remembering only the last one), then a `move` to move and rename it to the target.  (If you want to keep the original file, then do `copy` instead.)

The top part of the batch file then just calls the `MoveAndRename` subroutine multiple times, once for each source folder you want to look at.

If you want to avoid editing the batch file every month, change the third line to this:

```
set DateFolder=%1
```

and pass the date to the batch file as an argument:  `MonthlyProcess.bat 02.2013`.  Or you can set `DateFolder` using the `%date%` environment variable, but since it is formatted based on your locale settings, and it is well documented elsewhere, I will leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: Thx Nate, but It'll work only once. suppose next time I hv file Balance Sheet_20130406_1245678.xls" then it'll not work, I want's to fix this it. don't worry about folder it'll also change next time as F:\MY DOCUMENTS\zyx\04.2013

Comment: You haven't shown us a pattern yet.  I don't know what you want to rename "Balance Sheet_20130406_1245678.xls" to.

Comment: There, I've edited it so "Balance Sheet_*" gets renamed.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thx Nate, I'll check the batch and will get back to u soon...thanks for your afferts & help!

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd F:\MY DOCUMENTS\zyx
rem Process all file names
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B *.xls') do (
   rem Get base name before first underscore (ie: "Balance Sheet" or "FS")
   for /F "delims=_" %%b in ("%%a") do (
      rem Check if name have two words (ie: "Balance"/"Sheet" or "IC"/"Activities")
      for /F "tokens=1,2" %%c in ("%%b") do (
         rem If base name have just one word...
         if "%%d" equ "" (
            rem New name is that word (ie: "FS")
            set newName=%%c
         ) else (
            rem We don't know what goes here!
         )
      )
   )
   ren "%%a" "!newName!.xls"
)
```

We could complete previous program if you give us details on how to do so...

Comment: Please put these further details in your question, not in the comments.  1) they format better in the question, and 2) they are details that affect anyone wanting to help answer the question.

Comment: And if the only part you're unsure of is the renaming part, then I think my answer using a * in the `ren` command will do what you want.