# Convert a .bat batch file into Excel Macro?

Tags: excel, batch-file, xlsx

I have almost same nature of work as [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15660300/renamig-files-which-have-date-and-extension-number-can-be-variable). Is it possible to convert this `.bat` commands into an excel macro? If so, how would that be done?

Comment: You would be better served asking exactly what you want to do in an Excel VBA group.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can scan for files, and then rename/copy them from Excel via VBA code.

You use the File System Object

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278516.aspx

Some examples:

```
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   fso.MoveFile "d:\dummytest.txt", "d:\dummytest2.txt"

   fso.CopyFile "d:\dummytest.txt", "d:\dummytest2.txt"
```

As far as identifying which files to move around etc, you have to get a list of all the items in a folder and determine what your trigger will be for action. This is also tied to the File System Object, as one might expect.

Here is a sample of a code block I use to check if a filename I want to use exists already:

```
Flag = 1
While Flag > 0
    FileExists = (Len(Dir(Path & "\" & FileName, lngAttributes)) > 0)
    If FileExists Then
        FileName = BaseFilename & "(" & Flag & ").xlsx"
        Flag = Flag + 1
    Else
        Flag = 0
    End If
Wend
```

Here is a sample that loops through all the objects in a folder:

```
Set FileSys = New FileSystemObject
Set myFolder = FileSys.GetFolder(myDir)
dteFile = DateSerial(1900, 1, 1)
For Each objFile In myFolder.Files
    If objFile.DateLastModified > dteFile Then
        dteFile = objFile.DateLastModified
        strFilename = objFile.Name
    End If
Next objFile
```

This should get you going in the direction you are seeking.